# Which linear map maps $\begin{bmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2\end{bmatrix}^\top\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a_0&a_0+a_1&a_0+a_1+a_2\end{bmatrix}^\top$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Which linear map maps $\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_0+a_1\\a_0+a_1+a_2\end{bmatrix}$?

This should be very easy, but my understanding of matrices and linear maps isn't very deep yet.

Edit: What I'm asking is which matrix $A$ will $A\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_0+a_1\\a_0+a_1+a_2\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: You yourself are defining the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already a linear map! If you want a matrix, do this:

You could write it as $$\pmatrix{a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2}\mapsto\pmatrix{1a_0+0a_1+0a_2 \\ 1a_0+1a_1+0a_2 \\ 1a_0+1a_1+1a_2}$$

All you do is take those coefficients and write them into the matrix, i.e.

$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 &1&0 \\ 1&1&1}$$

which is the Matrix you are looking for.

Comment: Ah that's how you do it. Very easy, thanks!